# Swift 4 Array of Objects contains String Value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an dataArray

```
struct FirebaseDataGlobal {
    let symbol: String!
}

var dataArray = [FirebaseDataGlobal]()
```

I need to check if this array contains a specific String. Something like below.

```
if dataArray.contains("string") {
  print("string found")
}
```

How can i do this? Can i use a function like this if the dataArray is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains(where:)`:

```
if dataArray.contains { $0.symbol == "some string" } {
    print("found one")
}
```

Comment: Can this be used if the array is empty?

Comment: Sure. Give it a try.